# How do I customize the default icon of .txt files?

Tags: windows-8, icons

I wish to change the appearance of the default .txt icon

I have already replaced all the icon resources within all the different imageres.dll's (system32, syswow64, winsxs(amd64 and amdx86) but the default icon still appears. Are there more icon resources stored elsewhere in in the windows system files? If so where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DefaultProgramEditor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) to change the icon of the .txt files. Run it and click on the command "Icon":

[image]

Now select txt extension and select the icon you want to assign.

Comment: I went the long way and did it through imageres.dll and sehll32.dll editing but your method works too

Comment: nice to hear that it worked. Editing system fies is a bad idea.

Comment: i just tried DefaultProgramEditor. The one file type it does not seem to support is txt files.

Answer (score 1):

NirSoft FileTypesMan does the trick.

I'm running a notepad replacement (TED Notepad). TED Notepad changed the .txt icon and FileTypesMan let me change the .txt icon to an icon in any dll file. Nice integration with the Windows built-in dll-icon browser.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong but it changes **all** the icons that are openable with NotePad++. I only wanted to change the JS files. Association to an opening software, I don't want to change. Only the icon appearance.